# Do I have to install all updates in windows 7 to get 'get Windows 10 app'?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

My operating system is Windows 7 Professional. I want to upgrade to Windows 10. I checked whether my OS is genuine by running [`legitcheck.hta`](http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/downloads/GenerateHTA.aspx?displaylang=en&page=avsValidate) which reported my license is genuine. As per the requirement, I installed 5 important updates but unfortunately couldn't get the icon. Then I ran [`GW10Appdiagnostic.diagcab`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/2/2/F22D5FDB-59CD-4275-8C95-1BE17BF70B21/GW10Appdiagnostic.diagcab) which told that I need to get `KB2952664`. So, my question is it essential to install all the important updates or only the specific one above to get the icon? I'm telling so because even if I complete installing the important updates, many more updates come from nowhere; there seems to be no end to these; If I update now, within half hour or so, there will come many more. So, is it essential to install all those never-ending updates or just the `KB2952664`?

Comment: You only have to have Service Pack 1 installed.  Once you have Service Pack 1 installed my best advice, just use the Media Creation Tool, to perform the upgrade.  Otherwise download all available updates and wait for the prompt to upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks, sir; but as I'm really a novice to all these, may I ask you how to download Service Pack 1? Also, when I open `system properties`, I saw that in `windows edition`, it is written : `Windows 7 Professional` followed by copyright & then it is written `Service Pack 1`. Is it the same `Service Pack 1` you are talking of?

Comment: You download `Windows 7 Service Pack 1` through `Windows Update`.  If you are already running `Windows 7 Service Pack 1` then you can proceed with the upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for responding, sir. So, it is installed in my device, right? BTW, I want to get sure whether my OS is genuine; when I run the programme linked above, it shows : `Because Windows installed on your PC is genuine, enjoy the security, reliability and protection it provides`. So, can I take it my OS is genuine?? Thanks, again:)

Comment: I have answered the question, "Do I have to install all updates in windows 7 to update to Windows 10".  The answer to that question is you only need to be running `Windows 7 Service Pack 1`.  You seem to have other questions that are beyond the scope of this particular question.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry, sir; yes it is not related to the question I've asked ; I'll take it mine is genuine;) Thanks for responding.

Comment: @user36790 I tried to get the app "Get Windows 10" working , but i didn't succeed. Try using Media Creation Tool [from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). You need any blank USB flashdrive to put the Windows ISO on it. After that, you can boot from it and install Windows 10.

Comment: @snaks20: Thanks, I have downloaded it(18.7MB). Can you tell me how much memory do I need to download Windows 10 ? While progress became 3%, it already consumed 169.83 MB. I had few memory; so I stopped it:(

Comment: You need about 4 GB of free space so the app downloads it's  temp files of the installation in the Windows partition.

Comment: You can also select to upgrade directly from the app to Windows 10 so you don't loose your license